# String building based on user selection

Tags: c#

I have a series of checkboxes on a winform. Based on check box selection, application have to build a string.

What is best way of coding for problem.

thanks in advance.

-Harsha

Sol 1: Check every check box in individual 'if' statements and then build the string using string builder. 
But problem is we will have so many if statments.

Comment: What did you tried?! loop tru all checkboxes and if its checked add it to a string....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create List.

```
List<CheckBox> list = new List<CheckBox>()
 {
  checkBox1,checkBox2,checkBox3,checkBox4,checkBox5,checkBox6 
 };

var result =  (from checkbox in list
               select string.Format("{0} is {1}", 
               checkbox.Name, checkbox.Checked ? "Checked" : "Unchecked")).ToArray();

string str=string.Join(",",result);
```

OR

```
foreach(string s in result) {
   //
}
```

Comment: Superb . .thank you. I have a combo box also in the list of controls. based on the ckeckbox, combo box is enabled and user selects the choice from the combo box. How to handle this now. Thank you .. .

Comment: @Harsha: Glad you got it helpful :) Sorry! I didn't understood your question on comboboxes. Please edit your post and put appropriate explanation there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have Series of Check boxes. When user selects the check box, the ComboBox is enabled and user selects his choice from the comboBox. So, when I start building my string, I will check, user selected the checkbox or not. If selected, I will know what is his selection. That selected string from the comboBox is added to the string. This I have to do the all the check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... if there is many strings you can use StringBuilder for better performance rather than simple concatenation.

Comment: it depends on the number of concatenations. if you got short strings and the number of concatenations is small (e.g. < 10) the overhead of creating a StringBuilder may be bigger than concatenating strings directly.